# Sencha Touch 2 pop event issue under IE on Nokia Lumia 630

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have one very unpleasant issue under IE on Lumia. 
I'm developing mobile application with Sencha Touch 2 and 
use pop event of Main view to attach some logic:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-pop
Under all browsers the logic is called and application working properly instead 
IE on Nokia Lumia 630. The idea is to be executed some logic when 
the user click on back button and go to main view. Events attached to
backbutton event not fires at all. A also tried onbeforeunload on 
onunload events but there are also not called. 
I would be very grateful for any ideas and recommendations on how to solve this problem.